# how can i take integers from a user and know if they decrease, stay the same or grows

Tags: php

they asked us to write a program that asks the user to type 10 integers of an array. The program will then display either "the array is growing", "the array is decreasing", "the array is constant", or "the array is growing and decreasing." i don't know where to start.

Comment: You start by learning on how to write a simple PHP code first and when you're stuck with your logics, come back and give more information. Don't just sit here and wait for someone to do your whole homework for you.

Comment: Sky thank you for you concern, my mistake is not specifying what i was looking for when i posted my "question"' i was just looking for a little guidance as in where to find the info that i need, Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/PhP/

This may help you. Because it helps me start in php once.

Use it wisely and you will understand how php work

Cheers,

Poom

Comment: Try to follow the tutorial and test yourr code

Comment: @Downvoters:Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Another useful and easy site:
[Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/de/tracks/php)

There you can go learn step by step without installing PHP, a webserver or an IDE.
Just type and learn in the browser how PHP can help you.